# Django specific sql query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

how can I execute such query in django:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords_keyword WHERE id not in (SELECT keyword_id FROM sites_pagekeyword)
```

In the latest SVN release we can use:

```
keywords = Keyword.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM keywords_keyword WHERE id not in (SELECT keyword_id FROM sites_pagekeyword)')
```

But RawQuerySet doesn't support filter(), count(), indexing and other things. Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> <strike>Keyword.objects.exclude(id__in=PageKeyword.objects.all()</strike>

```
Keyword.objects.exclude(id__in=PageKeyword.objects.values('keyword_id'))
```

For future reference, [exclude is documented here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

---

**Edit:** Yes, you are right; I corrected my answer. See above.

---

**Edit:** Even more readable:

```
Keyword.objects.exclude(pagekeyword__in=PageKeyword.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it works not as expected,
here is the right solution for my task:

```
Keyword.objects.exclude(id__in=PageKeyword.objects.values('keyword_id'))
```